# Asp.net core mvc view attachments

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have attachments placed in **Shared Folder** in a server
I tried to access it using **`<a>` tag**

```
<a href="file:///C:">Open Attachments</a>
```

But it doesn't work in ASP.NET Core MVC for some reason.
If there is way to open shared folder in asp.net core please let me know
or point me to the best way to view attachments.

**Please note that for each order there are more than 6 attachments and the attachments for now pdf files**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use wwwroot folder for any physical files for your app
and use
`app.UseStaticFiles();`
in Configure Method in Startup file

so in wwwroot if you have folder called "Orders" and sub folders Order1, Order2, Order3
so you will access like below

```
<a href="~/Orders/Order1/Bill.Pdf">View Order1 Bill</a>
```

hope it's clear

Comment: Thank You for your reply, But can I let the wwwroot read from the shared folder or you mean to save the attachments in wwwroot ?

Comment: yes save attachments in wwwroot it's better and more professional